# Highcharts negative logarithmic scale solution stopped working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I generate graph code for a graph with a logarithmic scale with negative values. The result is in the fiddle below.

I made the function required to handle the negative values like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343645/overriding-log-scale-with-highcharts-export-server/63375446#63375446) and it worked perfectly. But since some days it does not function anymore. So I adjusted the code according to [this article](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/snippets/alternative-maths-plotting-negative-values-logarithmic-axis/) but it still does not work. See my [JSFidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HansR/dkp2acfq/):

```
(function (H) {
    H.addEvent(H.Axis, 'afterInit', function () {
        const logarithmic = this.logarithmic;

        if (logarithmic && this.options.custom.allowNegativeLog) {

            // Avoid errors on negative numbers on a log axis
            this.positiveValuesOnly = false;

            // Override the converter functions
            logarithmic.log2lin = num => {
                const isNegative = num < 0;

                let adjustedNum = Math.abs(num);

                if (adjustedNum < 10) {
                    adjustedNum += (10 - adjustedNum) / 10;
                }

                const result = Math.log(adjustedNum) / Math.LN10;
                return isNegative ? -result : result;
            };

            logarithmic.lin2log = num => {
                const isNegative = num < 0;

                let result = Math.pow(10, Math.abs(num));
                if (result < 10) {
                    result = (10 * (result - 1)) / (10 - 1);
                }
                return isNegative ? -result : result;
            };
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

I get an error 10 but the examples in [that description](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/10/) don't go anywhere.

What is going on and how do I repair?

Comment: Please take a look at this ticket: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13914

Comment: Thanks, have to study this more deeply though.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Highcharts made a change to the Axis definition.
The Y-axis was defined as:

```
yAxis:
{
  type: 'logarithmic',
  allowNegativeLog: true,
  title:
  {
    text: 'Regen Spreiding ( mm)'
  },
  min: 0.0,
  max: 25.40
},
```

And it is now required to be (at least it is working with this modification):

```
  type: 'logarithmic',
  custom:
  {
    allowNegativeLog: true,
  },
```

NOTE: this is together with the modified function H which now starts with :

```
H.addEvent(H.Axis, 'afterInit', function () {
```

---

If you landed here like I did, checkout [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/type-log-negative/) by Highcharts with working demo.