# Increase size of one of the series in R highchart

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to show a line and % changes in a single highchart plot, but the changes are very little and It can't be seen in the plot. I made a simplified code to show my problem:

```
a <- c(300,200, 400, 10, 40, 80)
b <- c(0.8, 2, -2, -1.5, -1.1, 2)
d<-cbind(a,b)
dt <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-06"), by = "days")

ts <- xts(d, dt )



highchart(type="stock") %>%
  hc_add_series(ts$a,
                type = "line",
                color="black") %>%
  
  hc_add_series(ts$b,
                type = "lollipop",
                color="red")
```

I need to increase the size of "ts$b" in the plot, how can I do it? I also tried with two axis, but It seems doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions to achieve that.

---

The first you mentioned - using two yAxis and manipulating their height and top distance.

**Example JS code:**

```
  yAxis: [{
      height: '90%',
      opposite: false
    },
    {
      visible: false,
      top: '83%',
      height: '15%',
    }
  ]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0826r7sh/

---

Another way is using a modified logarithmic axis. Negative values can't be plotted on a log axis, because by nature, the axis will only show positive values. In that case you need to use a custom extension according to the following thread:
[Highcharts negative logarithmic scale solution stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518108/highcharts-negative-logarithmic-scale-solution-stopped-working)

```
(function(H) {
  H.addEvent(H.Axis, 'afterInit', function() {
    const logarithmic = this.logarithmic;

    if (logarithmic && this.options.custom.allowNegativeLog) {

      // Avoid errors on negative numbers on a log axis
      this.positiveValuesOnly = false;

      // Override the converter functions
      logarithmic.log2lin = num => {
        const isNegative = num < 0;

        let adjustedNum = Math.abs(num);

        if (adjustedNum < 10) {
          adjustedNum += (10 - adjustedNum) / 10;
        }

        const result = Math.log(adjustedNum) / Math.LN10;
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
      };

      logarithmic.lin2log = num => {
        const isNegative = num < 0;

        let result = Math.pow(10, Math.abs(num));
        if (result < 10) {
          result = (10 * (result - 1)) / (10 - 1);
        }
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
      };
    }
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

.

```
  yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic',
    custom: {
      allowNegativeLog: true
    }
  },
```

**Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nw6osucm/